# How to customize emacs themes without editing the theme?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, dot-emacs

So I'm using [this theme](https://github.com/oneKelvinSmith/monokai-emacs/blob/master/monokai-theme.el) right now, and I want to customize it so that in orgmode levels 1-4 don't have larger :height's, but I don't want to edit the theme file. How do you do that?

Comment: Two questions.  1) Is there a strong reason not to edit the file?  Because it would only mean editing 4 lines.  2) Do you care about changing heights in modes other than `org-mode` (ie, is it okay if the theme does not change any heights anywhere)?

Comment: I suppose one advantage is that the customization (without editing the theme) is not lost when the theme is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source:  This theme provides [user options](https://github.com/oneKelvinSmith/monokai-emacs/blob/3fbef671fcf682351e5026825b3cd597af9b8b83/monokai-theme.el#L73) to customize the font size.

To use the same height for all Org Mode headings, add the following code to your `init.el`:

```
(setq monokai-height-minus-1 1
      monokai-height-plus-1  1
      monokai-height-plus-2  1
      monokai-height-plus-3  1
      monokai-height-plus-4  1)

(load-theme 'monokai 'no-confirm)
```

Comment: Those are the variables that affect the `org-mode` heights, but they also affect other things unrelated to `org-mode` (eg, latex headers and some other stuff).  If you don't mind affecting those other modes as well, this would be the customization to use.

Comment: I was looking for another solution that didn't affect the other things, but that being said I'm satisfied with this one/didn't believe the other one existed.

Comment: However it is interesting to note that this didn't work to me instead I had to define them using this

`
(defcustom monokai-height-plus-4 1.0
             "ALL THE SAME"
             :type 'number
             :group 'monokai)
`
type of a thing 5 times over. If I did the setq method, emacs crashed on loading a orgmode file. I think this is because it was rendering each character as 1px and that's a bad idea.